# Recursively applying MergeOption.NoTracking

Tags: entity-framework

I want to get an object from entity framework and return it along with all its related objects to the user. When I set the MergeOption to MergeOption.NoTracking, I do get the first related objects even after the entities/context object get destroyed. But when I try to get the related objects of the related objects, I get an exception saying that the entities object doesn't exists any more! I tried setting the MergeOption on all entities that are retrieved, but that didn't work. Any idea how to solve this problem?! Here is my code:

```
MyFirstObject myObject;

using (var entities = new MyEntities())
{
    entities.MyFirstObject.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
    entities.MySecondObject.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
    entities.MyThirdObject.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;

    myObject = entities.MyFirstObject.First();
}


myObject1.MySecondObjects..... // Works fine.
myObject1.MySecondObjects.MyThirdObjects.... // Throw an exception.
```

Answer (score 0):

`MergeOption` has no effect on this. `MergeOption` just tells EF how to handle materialized entities - `NoTracking` means that context must not track entities for changes. You must use eager loading.

```
myObject = entities.MyFirstObject
                   .Include("MySecondObjects.MyThirdObjects")
                   .First();
```